# Relations similar to $\sin(\pi/18) + \sin(5\pi/18) = \sin(7\pi/18)$

Tags: trigonometry

This I checked numerically (and can be proven analytically easily). I guess there are many similar relations between the numbers

$$\{ \sin\frac{m\pi}{q}, 1\leq m \leq q \} , $$

where $q$ is some integer.

Can anyone give some reference?

Comment: I think you would enjoy https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false   I will see whether I can find your specific item, if I give you a page number you can go there in the website.

Comment: see pages 491, 492. If my German were better I could explain

Answer (score 5):

More generally, let $T_n(x) + 1$ have a factor $Q(x)$ (over the rationals) where $T_n$ is the $n$'th Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.  A root of $Q(x)$ will be $\cos(j \pi/n)$ for some integer $j$.  Using trigonometric identities, we can then express $Q(\cos(\pi/n)) \sin(\pi/n)$ as a rational linear combination of sines of multiples of $j \pi/n$.  In your case
$$ T_{18}(x)+1 = 2 x^2 (4 x^2-3)^2 (64 x^6 - 96 x^4 + 36 x^2 - 3)^2 $$
and $$(64 \cos^6(\theta) - 96 \cos^4(\theta) + 36 \cos^2(\theta) - 3) \sin(\theta) = \sin(7\theta) - \sin(5 \theta) - \sin(\theta)$$
leading to your identity with $\theta = \pi/18$.

Similarly, using $$T_{20}(x) + 1 = 2\, \left( 2\,{x}^{2}-1 \right) ^{2} \left( 256\,{x}^{8}-512\,{x}^{6}+
304\,{x}^{4}-48\,{x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}
$$
we get
$$ \sin \left( {\frac {9\,\pi}{20}} \right) -\sin \left( {\frac {7\,\pi}{
20}} \right) -\sin \left( \frac{\pi}4 \right) +\sin \left( {\frac {3\,\pi}{
20}} \right) +\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{20} \right) = 0
$$

Answer (score 3):

I have studied this problem and found two kinds of solutions.

[Solution 1]

**$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{3 n}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi (n-k)}{3 n}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi (k+n)}{3 n}\right) $**

Example:

$ \cos\left(\frac{\pi }{15}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{4 \pi }{15}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{15}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{15}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{15}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{7 \pi }{15}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{15}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{5 \pi }{15}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{15}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{ \pi }{21}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{21}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{8 \pi }{21}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{21}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{5 \pi }{21}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{9 \pi }{21}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{21}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{4 \pi }{21}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{10 \pi }{21}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{ \pi }{27}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{8 \pi }{27}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{10 \pi }{27}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{27}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{7 \pi }{27}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{11 \pi }{27}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{27}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{27}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{12 \pi }{27}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{4 \pi }{27}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{5 \pi }{27}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{13 \pi }{27}\right) $

[Solution 2]

$ \cos \left(\frac{\pi  (6 k-3)}{5 (6 k-3)}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (10 k-5)}{3 (10 k-5)}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{(2 \pi ) (6 k-3)}{5 (6 k-3)}\right) $

Example:

$ \cos \left(\frac{ \pi }{5}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{  \pi }{3}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi }{5}\right) $

$ \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{15}\right)=\cos \left(\frac{ 5 \pi }{15}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{15}\right) $